# CSS animations acting weird

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Working on a hobby project to learn some html, css and js.

Been trying to solve a problem with an css animation acting weird. After the first iteration, it sometimes appear or disappear in the middle of the animation and other times it just flashes by way to fast. Been trying in multiple browsers and multiple computers/devices, all same result.

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ctjqo784/) (some code removed) and live example [here](http://interwebzfiket.se).

**index.html**

```
...
<body onload="init()">
<div class="leftanimation">Cool Gliding Text</div>
<div class="leftanimation">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</div>
<div class="leftanimation">How Cool Is This?</div>
<div class="leftanimation">Wwiiiieeee! </div>
<div class="leftanimation">Sssssswwwwoooosssshhh!</div>
<div class="leftanimation">Drive by text!</div>
<div class="leftanimation">More example text ...</div>
<div class="leftanimation">Last test text.</div>
...
```

**script.js**

```
function init() {

    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("leftanimation");

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        a[i].addEventListener("animationiteration", updateAnim);
    }
}

function updateAnim() {

    this.style.left = Math.random() * 7 + "%";
    //this.style.transform = "rotate(-90deg) translate(0px, " + Math.random() * 50 + 10 + "px)";
    this.style.fontSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 30 + "px";
    this.style.opacity = Math.random() * 0.5;
    this.style.animationDuration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 20 + "s";
    if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 1) {
        this.style.animationDirection = "normal";
    } else {
        this.style.animationDirection = "reverse";
    }
}
```

**style.css**

```
.leftanimation {
    position: fixed;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 5% 50%;
    animation: glide 0.01s infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: -2;
}

@keyframes glide {
    0% { top: -150%; animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; }
    100%  { top: 250%; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
}
```

Any ideas why it's behaving this way?

**Update**

The weird behavior seem to disappear if I remove `animationDuration` from `updateAnim()`. But, that does not solve my problem since I want the animation randomized.
Maybe it's just too much to handle for css animation?

Answer (score 0):

Just some tips: If you use addEventListener() you should collect them in an array to remove them if needed.

```
var eventListener = [];
element.addEventListener(event,callback,false);
eventListener.push([element,event,callback]);
```

To remove them just loop over the array:

```
while(var current = eventListener.pop()){
    current[0].removeEventlistener(current[1],current[2]);
}
```

This is just to learn it right from the start.

And:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 1
```

should be

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 1
```

If I see correct your problem happens when setting the animationDirection. It toggles the state to the default one given by css and after that runs the new animation with reversed order.

Try hiding the element and set the start position from where the animation should begin. After that show the element and start the animation. Maybe wrap the animationStart within a

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // setAnimationProperty etc
},0);
```

Comment: instead of `Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 1` you could just use `Math.random() < 0.5`

Comment: @user2429266 Thanks for the tips, always appreciated. The animations is part of the background, so I'm going to be lazy and not remove the eventlisteners. Resource handling is important, I know.
The problem was there before I started changing animationDirection. And hiding the text before I change the properties doesn't seem to work either (not sure I hid it properly though).

Comment: @vahanpwns I'll use that, but I'll change it to a `>` hehe.

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a number from 0 to less than 1, so I really recommend `<` for accuracy ;)

Comment: @vahanpwns don't let that 0.0001% diifference in the 2 chnaces exist, or some really bad things will happen.

Comment: @Bálint Testing in Chrome shows me that the floating point precision is 16 decimal places, therefore the difference is 0.00000000000001% and if I ignore such small things, worse things will happen just because they can.

Comment: @vahanpwns I tried not to overshoot it as I don't jave such tools on my habd currently.

Comment: @Bálint press F12 and click "Console" https://gyazo.com/5028c54cb2c02a12518c59c75da901fb it can save lives!

Comment: @vahanpwns I'm on a phone, I actually know how to use the interactive console.

Comment: Is it really possible to get an exact 50/50 chance with < or > ? Wouldn't it be .00000000000001% difference either way?